# Scrolling is slow with Cell based NSTableView

Tags: performance, cocoa, nstableview, nscell

I have set up a simple `NSTableView` with 10 columns that display only text.

I have exactly 500 records.

I have tried both using CocoaBindings and `NSTableViewDataSource` and in both cases, the scroll is slow when I scroll quickly up or down.

I'm currently working on Sierra and using Swift3.

I have tried to figure out with instrument what was using so much time.

[image: Instruments screenshot]

Apparently, a lot of work is done by `Core Animation`.

How can I achieve a perfect smooth scrolling using Cell based NSTableView?

The code used can be found here: https://gitlab.com/yageek/iCache.

The file that has been used to feed the data can be retrieve here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdqeq6sne3ejdw5/6661544_Strasbourg.gpx?dl=0

Comment: Did you try removing the Core Animation layers via IB, to see what changes?

Comment: From which component should I remove them ? Only the `NSTableView` instance ?

Comment: Uncheck all the CA checkboxes related to the table that are in the "View Effects Inspector" [in Xcode](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOyLxC0Z3-FAE7pd61rigIgPwv_dw4CC3Dc).

Comment: I just did it an I have exactly the same behaviour. I checked also with Instruments, i have similar results.

Comment: Well then I have no idea. Let's hope someone will find the cause of the issue. I suppose it would be a good idea to show the relevant parts of your code, where you are creating this content.

Comment: Will update the post and give a link to the source code.